Power Automate Trigger Condition - "OR" 3 Choice Values
I have a flow that I'm trying to set a trigger condition on.  I'm trying to trigger this flow if an item is modified, and if any of three Choice fields = "Request Approval".  This is what I've tried:
@or(equals(triggerOutputs()?[‘body/Architecture_x0020_Review_x0020_1'], 'Request Approval'),
equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Web_x0020_Services_x0020_Status'], 'Request Approval'),
equals(triggerOutputs()?[‘body/InfoSec_x0020_Status’])))

But the flow is telling me something is wrong when I try to save.  Can someone please help me with the syntax here?
Thank you.

Maybe because you didn't put the comparing value for the 3rd equals()
Try this:
@or(
equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Architecture_x0020_Review_x0020_1'], 'Request Approval'),
equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Web_x0020_Services_x0020_Status'], 'Request Approval'),
equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/InfoSec_x0020_Status'], 'Request Approval')
)


I've tested with this sample and it worked for me
@or( equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/LastName'], 'ABC'), 
equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/FirstName'], 'ABC'), 
equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Email'], 'ABC') )



THANK YOU!  This has been bugging me all day.
